# Python:Understanding inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

Am new to Python and was exploring Classes and Object. 
I have created a class,defined few function in it. Then I have created another class and was trying to inherit from the first class but got some error.
**Error:** class CTC(Salary):
NameError: name 'Salary' is not defined

**Base Class:**

```
class Salary:

    monthly=0.00
    name = ""

    def __init__(self,name,monthly):
        self.name = name
        self.monthly = monthly


    def display(self):
        print("name: ", self.name,  "Monthly Salary: ", self.monthly)
```

**Derived Class:**

```
class CTC(Salary):

    tax=0.00
    ctc=0.00
    def __init__(self,name,monthly,tax):
        Salary.__init__(self,name,monthly)
        self.tax = tax


    def calculateCTC(self):
         yearly = monthly*12
         totalTax= tax *12
         ctc = yearly - totalTax
         print("Total CTC: ", self.ctc)

         obj = CTC("Rishi",28700.00,1295.00)
         obj.display(self)
```

Can anyone explain me the root cause for the error?

Comment: pls correct the indentation..

Comment: Have you imported the base class in the CTC class ?

Comment: You have syntax errors in your Salary class aswell, you are missing ' : ' and the indentation is wrong

Comment: You forgot to put ":" after init and display methods

Comment: Are they in the same file?

Comment: I tested your code, the two classes in the same  file and it works.

Comment: **Can anyone explain me the root cause for the error?** You wrote the name Salary in a file, so python looked around the file and didn't see a definition for Salary.  If each class is in a separate file, then in the file that contains the class CTC, import the filename that contains the Salary class, e.g. `import myclasses`  (leave off the .py extension).

Comment: Both are kept in the same folder location..filename same as class name.. How can I import?Also indentation looks fine to me

Comment: `import salary`  should appear at the top of ctc.py.  Change all file names to lower case--as is the custom.

Comment: You should also use monthly like ``self.monthly``.

Comment: Have made some changes as per all suggestion. Now getting below error:

Comment: import Salary
class CTC(Salary):

     tax=0.00
     ctc=0.00
     def __init__(self,name,monthly,tax):
         Salary.__init__(self,name,monthly)
         self.tax = tax


         def calculateCTC(self):
             yearly = monthly*12
             totalTax= tax *12
             ctc = yearly - totalTax
             print("Total CTC: ", self.ctc)

             obj = CTC("Rishi",28700.00,1295.00)
             obj.display(self)

Comment: class Salary:

    monthly=0.00
    name = ""

    def __init__(self,name,monthly):
        self.name = name
        self.monthly = monthly


        def display(self):
        print("name: ", self.name,  "Monthly Salary: ", self.monthly)

Comment: Still getting error:  print("name: ", self.name,  "Monthly Salary: ", self.monthly)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: check indentations - maybe you mix "tab" with "four spaces"

Comment: @khelwood: no in different class file

Comment: @furas: checked all indentation. removed extra spaces..still not working... m using different files for both classes

Comment: @Poonuts: No luck yet. Refined my code by still stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I formated your code and it works for me.

```
class Salary:

    monthly=0.00
    name = ""

    def __init__(self,name,monthly):
        self.name = name
        self.monthly = monthly


    def display(self):
        print("name: ", self.name,  "Monthly Salary: ", self.monthly)


class CTC(Salary):

     tax=0.00
     ctc=0.00
     def __init__(self,name,monthly,tax):
         Salary.__init__(self,name,monthly)
         self.tax = tax


     def calculateCTC(self):
         yearly = monthly*12
         totalTax= tax *12
         ctc = yearly - totalTax
         print("Total CTC: ", self.ctc)

         obj = CTC("Rishi",28700.00,1295.00)
         obj.display(self)
```

Comment: Are you using same file to embed both the classes? As I m using different files

Comment: @RISHI KHANNA I my case i use the same file, if you like i will use two file for demostration.

Comment: Got it finally. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

I put all code in one file (with minor modifiactions) and it works form me.

```
class Salary:

    def __init__(self, name, monthly):
        self.name = name
        self.monthly = monthly

    def display(self):
        print("name: ", self.name,  "Monthly Salary: ", self.monthly)


class CTC(Salary):

    def __init__(self, name, monthly, tax):
        Salary.__init__(self, name, monthly)
        self.tax = tax
        self.ctc = 0.00 # create with default value

    def calculateCTC(self):
        yearly = self.monthly*12 # with `self`
        totalTax = self.tax*12 # with `self`
        self.ctc = yearly - totalTax # with `self`
        print("Total CTC: ", self.ctc)

# without indentation
obj = CTC("Rishi", 28700.00, 1295.00)
obj.display() # without `self`
```

if you need it in separated files

salary.py

```
class Salary:

    def __init__(self, name, monthly):
        self.name = name
        self.monthly = monthly

    def display(self):
        print("name: ", self.name,  "Monthly Salary: ", self.monthly)
```

main.py

```
from salary import Salary

class CTC(Salary):

    def __init__(self, name, monthly, tax):
        Salary.__init__(self, name, monthly)
        self.tax = tax
        self.ctc = 0.00

    def calculateCTC(self):
        yearly = self.monthly*12 # with `self`
        totalTax = self.tax*12 # with `self`
        self.ctc = yearly - totalTax # with `self`
        print("Total CTC: ", self.ctc)

# without indentation
obj = CTC("Rishi", 28700.00, 1295.00)
obj.display() # without `self`
```

Comment: Hi furas it worked. But still I could not understand where I was missing

Comment: Also, you have removed all the global variables. If I am trying to call calculateCTC after declaring global variables its throwing same error again

Comment: @RISHIKHANNA Actually, he has not removed the global variables, when defining a variable with `self` it will be in a global scope to that class, and any class derived from that class. when you define a variable without the `self` keyword, the variable will only be in a local scope.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike Java, which forces developer to put each `class` in each file, Python is more flexible. In Python you can write as much code as you want in a single file, meaning that you can have both of your `class`es in a single file, without needing to `import` anything. The diffrence is in `import`ing. Java doesn't need you to `import` any of your project files, Python on the other hand requires you to `import` **anything** that is in external packages, no matter where are they kept. So just import your `Salary` to the file with `CTC`.

Comment: Yes. just wanted to try different way. Imported Salary to CTC but still no luck

Comment: Did you just `import salary`? if so you need to refer to your class with `salary.Salary`. You can however directly import the class with `from salary import Salary`. I assume that your file is named `salary`